# How can I solve download FileTransfer error code 3 in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to download a file to my android phone with a phonegap app. But I always get upload error code 3. I have tried to dump all the data to make it clear.

added to my config.xml :

```
<access origin="http://example.com/" />
```

index.js :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {

    alert("FileSystem : " + fileSystem.name); // FileSystem : persistent
    var rootDeviceUrl = fileSystem.root.toURL();
    alert("Root device Url : " + rootDeviceUrl); // Root device Url : file:///storage/emulated/0/

    var downloadURL = 'http://example.com';

    new FileTransfer().download(downloadURL,
                                rootDeviceUrl,
                                function(entry) {
                                    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    alert("download error source " + error.source); // download error source http://example.com
                                    alert("download error target " + error.target); // download error target file:///storage/emulated/0/
                                    alert("upload error code " + error.code); //upload error code 3
                                });

}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: you gotta use request filesystem URL instead. Check out this working sample - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations  let me know if it helps so that I can post it as answer. cheers

Comment: Anny idea what line of code from my original code i need to change?

Comment: as I mentioned filesystem should be changed to filesystemurl.. The example link is right up there

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'true' parameter after fail callback function, see below code

```
new FileTransfer().download(downloadURL,
                                rootDeviceUrl,
                                function(entry) {
                                    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    alert("download error source " + error.source); // download error source http://example.com
                                    alert("download error target " + error.target); // download error target file:///storage/emulated/0/
                                    alert("upload error code " + error.code); //upload error code 3
                                }, true);
```